# DROP FOREIGN KEY not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

On PHPMyAdmin, I would like to ***DROP*** a ***FOREIGN KEY*** with

```
ALTER TABLE information DROP FOREIGN KEY IDX_29791883B30676A7
```

Because when I do the next query it's not working:

```
ALTER TABLE information DROP INDEX IDX_29791883B30676A7
```

> Cannot drop index 'IDX_29791883B30676A7': needed in a foreign key constraint

However, the second query as the error that the index is use as foreigner key. 
Fine, but when I do the first query I get this error:

> Can't DROP 'IDX_29791883B30676A7'; check that column/key exists

So the questions are:

- How do I acually *check that*,
- How can I finally *drop that key*.

Comment: The name of the foreign key by default has the 'FK' prefix not 'IDX'. Looks like you are trying to drop an index and not a foreign key. You need to find the correct name of the constraint you want to drop

Comment: Perfect, the name of the index was not the same as the foreigner key, and was in fact FK. You should post as an answer.

Comment: What's the name of the foreign key?

Comment: It was FK_29791883B30676A7.

Comment: OK I'll put the query in an answer so that the post is not left unanswered for future references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys by default are prefixed with 'FK' not 'IDX'. You are trying to remove an index instead of a foreign key. You mentioned that the foreign key is: `FK_29791883B30676A7` so the correct way to remove it will be:

```
ALTER TABLE information DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_29791883B30676A7
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a foreign key has been created, you may find that you wish to drop the foreign key from the table. You can do this with the ALTER TABLE statement in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with foreign keys, well I found a solution to removing constraint. For first take a look at:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE information;
```

You will found the name of the rule, and then just drop it:

```
ALTER TABLE information DROP CONSTRAINT `name_of_rule`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE information DROP FOREIGN KEY IDX_29791883B30676A7;
ALTER TABLE information DROP INDEX IDX_29791883B30676A7;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```